# How to pass Objective-C value to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, objective-c, wkwebview

Now I would like to pass an Objective-C object (String) to JavaScript (in WKWebView).

Want to load an Objective-C variable into JavaScript at the timing when `window.onload` is executed, as shown below.

```js
var objcString = "";

window.onload = function() {
    objcString = objc.getObjcString();

    execXxxWhenWindowOnload(objcString);
}
```

How can I implement Objective-C function?

Answer (score 0):

you can use evaluateJavaScript function for passing value. Here is an example of it please check

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation {
  NSString *strFunction = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"'function name'('%@')",'value'];
  [self.webview evaluateJavaScript:strFunction completionHandler:nil];
}
```

Comment: Which is executed first, didFinishNavigation or window.onload?
If window.onload is executed first, then there is a problem with this method.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

- it's a URL request you initiate from the app that will land you on the page(opposed to navigating to some link later on)
- you don't want to pass sensitive data

you could consider using a query param (albeit be wary not to clash with some existing query param names in the url).

```
NSString *yourCustomString = @"value";
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.yourserver.com?myParam=%@", yourCustomString];
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:urlString]]];
```

In the js counterpart you'd handle that like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const myParam = urlParams.get('myParam');
    execXxxWhenWindowOnload(myParam);
}
```

I haven't found a way to inject custom js before `window.onload` using `WKUserScript` / `WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentStart` duo.